# How Recognize Extra Macro Arguments?

Tags: c++, macros

I have such simple macro which has two argument:

```
#define DO_SOMETHING(__X__ , __Y__) \
do{ \
    __X__;\
    __Y__;\
} while (0);
```

Here there are three examples of how I use this macro, besides **console output**:

```
DO_SOMETHING(cout << "Part 1";); //=> Part1 //NoErr
DO_SOMETHING(cout << "Part 1"; , cout << "Part 2";); //=> Part1 Part2
DO_SOMETHING(cout << "Part 1";, cout << "Part 2";, cout << "Part3";); //=> Part1 Part2 //NoErr
```

I think it's due to the way comma `,` is interpreting in macro.

**Question:** However, I'd like to see a compile-time error for case 1 and 3. How can I achieve it?

**PS:** I can't use `function` instead since I need the context! For example the first parameter may be a `return;` statement.

**EDIT:** Real macro is not such easy. In fact, we have a repetitive switch-case all over project that we want to have a mechanism to **check if we handle are cases in all switches**. we could do it by (1) **Polymorphism** (2) **function-call**. solution (1) is not applicable since we will have a ultra-huge class with hardly cohesion codes, and solution (2) is not possible because we need Context.

**PS:** We do need to compiler on both *Visual Studio* and *GCC*, as well as *xCode environment*.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but don't use names beginning with two leading underscores, or names beginning with one leading underscore followed by an upper-case letter. Those names are reserved by the implementation (compiler and standard library) in *all* scopes, including macro names.

Comment: What is the purpose of this macro? That is, what problem does it solve? There may be a better way to solve the actual problem.

Comment: Which compiler are you using though?

Comment: Macros are there to simplify repetitive stuff, or allow easy portability of some calls across platforms or dependencies. They are not extensively elaborated beyond the point of their necessity. You are supposed to code in C/C++, not in macros.

Comment: "*like to see a compile-time error*" do you see a warning?

Comment: By the way, g++ produces the desired compilation errors, as does Visual C++ - just like they're supposed to.

Comment: GCC (CPP) does as well. @molbdnilo

Comment: @molbdnilo Check my edit.

Comment: @alk Check my edit.

Comment: @Havenard Check my edit

Comment: So again: Do you get a warning on case 1 and 3?

Comment: @alk Yes. I saw it before. But I'm looking for any better solution.

Comment: At least for GCC just compile with option `-Werror`.